# Subsets $A$ of rational numbers with $| \Bbb{Q} \setminus (A-A)|=2m$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, rational-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $m$ and let $\mathbb{Q} \cap (m, +\infty) = \{ r_k \}_{k \ge m}$. If
$$A:= \left\{ m+r_m+\sum_{k=m}^n r_k : n \ge m-1\right\},$$
then we know that $A-A= \Bbb{Q} \setminus ([-m,m]\setminus \{0\})$.

But, we are looking for a subset $A$ of rationals such that $A-A= \Bbb{Q} \setminus \{ \pm1,\cdots,\pm m \}$ or (if it does not exist) $| \Bbb{Q} \setminus (A-A)|=2m$. Are there such subsets $A$?

Comment: When you want to find such numbers it's better to write: $$(r_k)_{k\geq m} := \{ x\in \mathbb Q: x>m, m\in \mathbb N\},$$ because you are excluding neutral $m=0$ and $$B:=\{ y\in \mathbb Z: 1\leq |y|\leq m, \mathbb N\}$$

Comment: Also, in: $$\mathbb Q\setminus ([-m,m]\cap \mathbb Q)$$ '$\cap\mathbb Q$' is redundant because you can't take irrational numbers from $\mathbb Q$ anyway. What happens with $0$ when $m>1$? Because $B$, as I rewrote it, isn't equal to $[-m,m]$

Comment: Thanks for your attention to the question. You are right, I edited it.

Comment: You' re welcome! (:

Comment: But the thing I would put the accent on is that $\{r_k\}_{k\geq m}\subset\mathbb Q$ and, therefore, countably infinite, while the intersection in the first line tells that, kind of implicitly, in my opinion. (:

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A_i = \{0\} \cup \big((i,i+1)\cap \mathbb{Q}\big)$ satisfies $$A_i-A_i = \mathbb{Q} \cap \big((-i-1,-i)\cup (-1,1) \cup (i,i+1)\big)$$

Since your $A \subset [0,\infty),$ we can just union that $A$ with our $A_i$ shifted sufficiently far left to get an example.  That is, take

$$A \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{m-1}(A_i - 3mi)$$

Comment: May I ask what notation $A-A$ means? There are some differences between notations we use in our country and the international ones, so I ask. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya The typical definition, and the one I assume is in use here, is $$A-A := \{a_1-a_2 : a_1,a_2 \in A\}$$  That is, it's the set of differences of elements in $A$.  Does that match your usage?

Comment: we used similar in linear algebra when defining the quotient space and vector equivalence classes (if translated correctly). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Brian Moehring Thanks. Could you please give a sketch of proof for your claim